# Adding strictly business logic predicates to the LEFT JOIN conditions

Tags: sql, outer-join

This is theoretical/best practice request for opinions.

I have grown accustomed to viewing the WHERE clause and the JOIN conditions as a good place to "host" any business logic that will make my query as precise as possible.

But it was brought to my attention that adding unrelated business logic as a JOIN condition might be against "best practices". For example:

```
         SELECT a.Id, b.Id
           FROM foo AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bar AS b ON a.Id = b.Id 
                        AND GETDATE() >= "18/5/2011"
```

The example is a little naive: in real life the additional condition is really required by the caller and not having it would actually produce untrue result (that the caller will have to filter in the code).

Note that with OUTER joins and when logic dictates it, placing the condition in the WHERE clause is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I have always made it a practice to put as many conditionals into the `JOIN` statements as possible for that reason, and have read in a number of places, including Joe Celko's writings, that it's a best practice to do so.

`JOIN` conditions are going to be faster as they exclude rows from being added to the combined table altogether, where a `WHERE` clause is used after the tables are combined based on the join conditions - and on, potentially, a much larger data set. In many cases, I'm sure the optimizer handles this intelligently and applies WHERE conditions where possible, but that's speculation, and would be engine specific at best.